# How to remove html comments using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm cleaning text from a crawled website, but I don't want any html comments in my data, so do I have to parse it out myself or is there an existing function to do so?

I've tried doing this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as S
soup = S("<!-- t --> <h1>Hejsa</h1> <style>html{color: #0000ff}</style>")
soup.comment # == None
soup.style   # == <style>html{color: #0000ff}</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search form HTML comments, you can use `bs4.Comment` type:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html_doc = '''
    <!-- t --> <h1>Hejsa</h1> <style>html{color: #0000ff}</style>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# print comment:
comment = soup.find(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
print( comment )
```

Prints:

```
t
```

---

To extract it:

```
comment = soup.find(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))

# extract comment:
comment.extract()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<h1>
 Hejsa
</h1>
<style>
 html{color: #0000ff}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex.

```
import re
html = "<!-- t --> <h1>Hejsa</h1> <style>html{color: #0000ff}</style>"
html = re.sub('<!--[\s\S]*-->', '', html).strip()
print(html)
```

Result:

```
<h1>Hejsa</h1> <style>html{color: #0000ff}</style>
```